# Where to find Screen pinning option in GenyMotion emulator?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion, android-screen-pinning

As android Introduces **Screen Pinning**  in *Android 5.0* and higher, I want to access that feature in **Genymotion virtual device** but I can't find any option in dev setting, anybody have any idea how to find this feature in Genymotion device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [site](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6118421?hl=en) says you can go into Settings->Security and you will see this:

[image][image]

and then when you press the overview button(recent apps button) you will come up with this screen:

[image]

able to pin anything you want. **But** if you want to get out of the Pinned Screen you will have to press back button and overview button at the same time and i dont know how you do this in genymotion.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

**To enable the feature you'll need to follow these steps:**

1.Launch the Settings app on your Android device.

2.Scroll down until you find the Security option. Tap on it.

3.At the bottom of the Security page tap on Screen pinning.

4.Slide the switch to the On position.